# How can i hide my html source code from getting copied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i hide my page source from getting copied just like https://www.google.com

Please help me with any solution.
Is there any plugin need to add,please suggest me.

Comment: this is not possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hiding html sourcecode is not possible. The browser has to understand what you want to show and therefore needs to know your code.

Google does not encrypt the sourcecode. It is hard to read because a lot is going on but if you copy the sourcecode and paste it in notepad. You will have the same html markup.

Comment: Is code obfuscation different from encryption? Curious to know if HTML code can't be encrypted, how does this service - http://myobfuscate.com or others work?

Comment: @Orions Javascript is capable of inserting HTML code. the website  myobfuscate.com creates a javascript function that outputs the html in a very long javascript code. However, if you copy the function and paste it on another website you will have the same output.

This does hide the sourcecode, however using inspect element (F12) shows the html nonetheless